# Can two non-isomorphic local domains have isomorphic quotient field and residue field?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Suppose $R,R'$ are non-isomorphic local domains with maximal ideals $\mathfrak{m,m'}$. Can they have isomorphic quotient field and residue field?

Comment: You could take $k[[t^2,t^3]] \subseteq k[[t]]$.

Comment: @Youngsu: Nice. This is an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the comment posted by Youngsu: Take $R=k[[t^2,t^3]]\subset R'=k[[t]]$.